# robot_upstart perminantly change ownership

Tags: ros, linux, permissions, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using robot_upstart to launch my code. My code needs to access several ports that are owned by root (dev/USB0, dev/USB1, dev/ACM0, etc...). I changed the owner of these files to the same user that I used to run the robot_upstart intall script by running `sudo chown ubuntu /[file name]`

Now I've restarted the computer which has changed the ownership back to root. I started researching how to change the ownership permanently but some people were saying that this is bad practice. Is this so? If so how should I fix this? If not how to I change the owner permanently?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247219/robot_upstart-perminantly-change-ownership/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note the section in the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html) that tell you that `robot_upstart` does *not* run under your own user:

> The roslaunch which executes **does not have its user’s group memberships**.

Adding your user to `dialout` does not work.

See [robot_upstart: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0](http://answers.ros.org/question/207892) for a related question (almost a duplicate, really).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2017-12-06**:
That does not make sense.The script uses setuidgid and sets to the user specified, which is in the diarlout group. When I do the same thing in my case and look at the processes run in htop the process  user is correct. So how can the process run as the specified ser but not have the permissions user